# Accessing Option type members

Tags: scala

Say I have:

```
case class User(
  id: Int,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  age: Int,
  gender: Option[String])
```

To declare an Option value I type:

```
val x:Option[User] = Some(User(1,"x","x",13,Some("ss")))
```

how do I access x's members, for example

```
x.age
```

I get the following error with the above declaration

```
error: value age is not a member of Option[User]
   x.age
```

Is this remotely possible

Comment: You probably should not open questions for things like this that can be easily googled.  Nonetheless, here's a good article explaining how to use scala's option type.

Also note, it was the first result I found when googling "using scala option"

http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html

Comment: I read that article (I'm actually half way through it). there's x.map(_.age) but that just returns a Some. I want the actual member type rather than another option.

Comment: "how do I access x's members" This question points to a misunderstanding of what is happening. `x` does not have any User members. `x` is an Option. This optionality must be dealt with first before talking about `User` members.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to pattern matching for retrieving data from a monad is use `flatMap`:

```
x.flatMap(user => Option(user.age))
// res128: Option[Int] = Some(13)
```

I just realize this doesn't really answer your question, but I'll still leave it here as an alternative option, unless there are different opinions.

---

While leaving above answer as is, I think a more idiomatic way to get values from option is `getOrElse`:

```
x.map(_.age).getOrElse(0)
// res140: Int = 13
```

Or `get`:

```
x.map(_.age).get
// res141: Int = 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Study the [Scaladoc page for Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html).  There are a surprising number of methods that return concrete types (i.e. non-monadic).  Examples include `fold`, `getOrElse`, `head`, `max`, `product`, `sum`, and many more.

It's worth noting, however, that most of these are not safe at runtime (will throw an error if called on a `None`).  It's best to use methods that will supply a default when called on a `None`. (`fold` and `getOrElse` are good.)

Answer (score 1):

So many answers ...  for completeness, I think a cool way to work with Options (and any Monads for that matter) is to use a for-comprehension.

```
for( user <- x ) yield user.age
```

It will also work for arbitrary nested Options, say:

```
case class Address(street: String, number: Option[Int])
case class User(name: String, addr: Option[Address]) 

val u = Some(User("foo", Some(Address("bar", Some(2)))))

for( user <- u; addr <- user.addr; n <- addr.number) yield n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access using pattern matching

```
val x: Option[User] = Some(User(1,"x","x",13,Some("ss"))
    x match {
      case Some(user) => user.age
      case None => 0
    }
```

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Option.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is pattern matching. It lets you test the type of your `x`.
You simply need to write:

```
x match{
    case None => /* Your code if it's None */
    case Some(user) => /* Here user has type User, so you can call its methods */
}
```